# laravel array groupBy specific column value

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm working with arrays in laravel and I have a result like this:

```
   $datesArr = [ {
        "day": "monday",
        "date": "2021-05-03"
    },
    {
        "day": "monday",
        "date": "2021-05-10"
    },
    {
        "day": "monday",
        "date": "2021-05-17"
    }
]
```

what I want is this:

```
   {
    "day": "monday",
    "dates" : [
       {"date": "2021-05-03"},
       {"date": "2021-05-10"},
       {"date": "2021-05-17"},
     ]
    }
```

Comment: what you've tried so far? and btw that is JSON, not an php array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all that tried to help me. I came with an idea how to solv it.
I will try to explain it here.
First I got all days that I have stored. then:

```
$daysArr = array();
                foreach($days as $key => $day){
                    $datesArr = array();
                    for($i = 0;$i< 8;$i++){
                        $newDate['date'] = now()->next($key)->addWeeks($i)->toDateString();
                        array_push($datesArr,$newDate);
                    }
                    $test['day'] = $key;
                    $test['dates'] = $datesArr;
                    array_push($daysArr,$test);
                    unset($datesArr);
                }
        return $daysArr;
```

I did double array_push and foreach "new day" , I unset $datesArr to get empty array for pushing new dates of "new day".
Hope I was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Hope to help you (should convert all to array)

```
public static function  buildArrayGroupBy($key, $data , $lockKey = null) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
            if(!is_null($lockKey)){
                $result[$val[$key]][] = $val[$lockKey];
            }else{
                $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
            }

        }else{
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Collection's [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) function.

The output will be in the format below but it'll do the job.

```
$datesArr = [
    "monday" => [
        {
            "day": "monday",
            "date": "2021-05-03"
        },
        {
            "day": "monday",
            "date": "2021-05-10"
        },
        {
            "day": "monday",
            "date": "2021-05-17"
        }
    ]
]
```

For exact output like mentioned, You can use [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups).

```
$data->mapToGroups(function($i) {
    return ['day' => $i['day'],
            'dates' => [
                 'date' => $i['date']
           ]];
});
```

P.S: You might have to change it a little bit according to your requirements.

Comment: thank you Jerry, I was using this groupBy function , but I need that specific king of return.

Answer (score 0):

Let's generate some dummy data based on your requirements:

```
foreach(range(1,100) as $rangeTbs){
  $carbon = \Carbon\Carbon::now()
    ->addDays(rand(1,20))
    ->addMonths(rand(1,2));

  $dateArrayTbs[] = [
            'day' => $carbon->format('l'),
            'date' => $carbon->format('Y-m-d'),
        ];
}
```

Now we can convert array into collection:

```
$collection = collect($dateArrayTbs)
         //Grouping By day 
            ->groupBy('day')
        //Now Converting into Desired Format
            ->map(function(Collection $collection,$day){
              return [
                'day' => $day,
                'dates' => $collection->sortBy('date')->toArray(),
              ];
            });
```

Comment: Please refrain from apologising for late answers on Stack Overflow. This site is specifically built to allow people to answer at any time they like. What constitutes a good answer may change over time, and old answers may become less relevant. Thus, if you have an answer to a question, just post it, minus any commentary about its age.